# Wordpress pass PHP data to Javascript With Callback

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

It is pretty clear how to pass data from PHP to Javascript in PHP via [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

> Is it possible to create a callback to query javascript for a value
>   from PHP?

More specifically:
I use PHP to echo a Javascript selector. I would like to return the array of id's of the selected items to my PHP when my PHP button "Add to Cart" is clicked to pass it on to the cart.

How to make PHP ask Javascript for a value also answers the question.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Think the other way around. When user does something...send data to php. Can use a form submit or use ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, you would need to implement an AJAX call here on a certain action (e.g. Add to Cart button click). The AJAX call can pass in whatever data you like, including an array of element IDs matched by some criteria as you have requested.

Then you will need to build something to handle the custom AJAX request, of which there are already good guides e.g. [AJAX in Plugins - Wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)